# Query with checkbox and combobox in Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access, checkbox, combobox, ms-access-2010

Good afternoon
This is my query:

```
SELECT Reference.quote_date AS [Quote Date]
  , Reference.agent_ID AS Agent
  , Reference.ref_ID AS ReferenceID
  , Reference.ref_number AS [Ref Number]
  , Customer.title_id AS Title
  , Customer.name AS Name
  , Customer.surname AS Surname
  , Customer.postcode AS Postcode
  , Customer.telephone AS Telephone
  , Reference.location_ID AS Location
  , Reference.policy_ID AS Product
  , Reference.price AS Price
  , Reference.status_ID AS Status
  , Reference.source_ID AS Source
  , Reference.calltype_ID AS [Call Type]
  , Reference.prize_draw AS [Prize Draw]
  , Reference.Call_back_date AS [Call back date]
  , Reference.call_back AS [Call back]
  , Reference.IsCompleted AS Completed
  , Reference.comments AS Comments
FROM Customer INNER JOIN Reference 
  ON Customer.[customer_ID] = Reference.[customer_ID]
WHERE (((Reference.agent_ID)=[Forms]![Call_Back_Search1]![Combo5]) 
  AND ((Reference.Call_back_date) 
    Between [Forms]![Call_Back_Search1]![StartDateTxt] And [Forms]![Call_Back_Search1]![EndDatetxt]));
```

It Currently shows all call backs within certain criteria selected in Call_Back_Search1 form:
- date criteria: between Start and date:End
- and allows to select the Agent (Combobox05). 
I wish to add additional criteria to my query :
checkbox called "Completed" to be not ticked 
- to show results based only on date range selected (leaving combobox blank)
Wonder if I can ask you for any suggestions
Thank you

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and edit your question to be better readable.

Comment: Where are you putting the query? Control source of a form object? Is it a subform? Please clarify your desired use of the checkbox as well.

Comment: Hi @ChristopherD. I actually mange to get this issue resolved myself.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone will find my answer useful 
Code is listed below :

SELECT Reference.quote_date AS [Quote Date], Reference.agent_ID AS Agent, Reference.ref_ID AS ReferenceID, Reference.ref_number AS [Ref Number], Customer.title_id AS Title, Customer.name AS Name, Customer.surname AS Surname, Customer.postcode AS Postcode, Customer.telephone AS Telephone, Reference.location_ID AS Location, Reference.policy_ID AS Product, Reference.price AS Price, Reference.status_ID AS Status, Reference.source_ID AS Source, Reference.calltype_ID AS [Call Type], Reference.prize_draw AS [Prize Draw], Reference.Call_back_date AS [Call back date], Reference.call_back AS [Call back], Reference.comments AS Comments, Reference.IsCompleted
FROM Customer INNER JOIN Reference ON Customer.[customer_ID] = Reference.[customer_ID]
WHERE IIF(IsNull(Forms!Call_Back_Search1!Combo5),True,(Reference.agent_ID)=Forms!Call_Back_Search1!Combo5) And ((Reference.Call_back_date) Between Forms!Call_Back_Search1!StartDateTxt And Forms!Call_Back_Search1!EndDatetxt) And (([Reference.IsCompleted])=0);